# Qt4, QToolbox: Keeping (some) child widgets enabled/accessible with toolbox being disabled

Tags: qt, qt4, widget, activation

I'm currently building a data aquisition application, in which UI I placed the controls for mutually exclusive aquisition modes in the different subpages of a QToolbox, **where the currently selected QToolbox item selects the aquisition mode parameter.**

One desired feature is to *lock* the UI – after changing the parameters, the changes have to be *applied/confirmed*, being able to lock the UI elements against accidental changes is a feature, implemented by simply disabling the widgets. **And since the aquisition mode is one parameter this also means locking down the QToolbox.** However some controls within the toolbox need to stay unlocked since their effect is immediate.

So here's the question: In Qt4, how can I keep child widgets enabled and accessible while their container has been disables. Or how can I emulate the behaviour and look of such a setup?

*Please don't suggest changes in the UI. I had all people in my research group testing different UI concepts and the current one is the one that ist most intuitive and straightforward to use.*

Comment: Most QWidget subclasses have setEnabled function. Assuming all the items in your QToolBox are subclasses of QWidget(QPushButton etc) , won't setting setEnabled(false) solve your problem ?

Comment: @Abhijith: I am aware of setEnabled, it being the function I use to disable the QToolbox in the first place. And unfortunately the setEnabled(false) on the QToolbox influences the children, too.

Comment: well what i was actually asking is , can't you call setEnabled on each item instead of the QToolbox ?

Comment: @Abhihith: The toolbox itself sets one parameter too, namely the aquisition mode. And since the aquisition mode is a to be locked parameter I have to disable the toolbox then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I "solved" the problem by using a combination of QComboBox + QStackedWidget instead of a QToolBox and disable the combobox to lock it down.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable the container, all its child widgets will be disabled. I don't think you can change this behaviour. So you have to disable separately all the child widgets that you don't want to remain enabled.

Comment: Well, unfortunately in the current UI scheme I have to disable the container, too, since the selected tab/toolbox item sets a parameter, namely the aquisition mode. It would be sufficient if I could lock the selected tab/toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the page of QToolbox using the UI function: `setItemEnabled` and pass the index of the page through the UI function: `indexOf` and your boolean.

Here's a little code:

ui->toolbox->setItemEnabled(ui->toolbox->indexOf(ui->page),false);